# Having more than one PDF field on a table in Django

Tags: django, pdf, database-design

I am making a Manual admin as part of a big project. Each manual has a brand, a model and has at least one PDF.

from django.db import models

```
class Manual(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manual = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdf')
```

Two questions:

- How can I model a PDFField, or a generic field, rather than an Image field?
- Is it possible for the manual field to have more than one file without having to make another table?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a FileField? If you need to have more than one pdf per manual, use a one-to-many relationship as a ForeignKey in another table. There's nothing wrong with having multiple models.

Comment: Why don't you add that as a response so I can accept and give you credit?

Comment: Sure, I've added an answer with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to have more than one pdf per manual, use a one-to-many relationship as a ForeignKey in another table. There's nothing wrong with having multiple models.

```
class Manual(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ManualPDF(models.Model):
    manual = models.ForeignKey(Manual)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf')
```

In your view code (or form or model code) you can then get all the PDFs for a manual using `_set` which will return a QuerySet of the ManualPDF model objects:

```
some_manual = Manual.objects.get(id=1)
some_manual_pdfs = some_manual.manualpdf_set.all()
```

There more info in the official Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/